# Elements' boxes (box model) overlapping each other in Chrome?

Tags: css-float, cross-browser, css

I'm having a cross-browser compatibility issue with Chrome vs FF.

Here is the web inspected from Chrome, you'll see that the box for the DIV #content is overlapping the box for the H3.

[image]

In FF, the #content DIV does not overlap:

[image]

The issue is the difference in overlap is causing the background behind the Doctors' heads (the light blue canvas texture) which is relatively positioned DIV to be off. In Chrome is positioned well, in FF the green "view all button" is beyond the background.

Link to the site: http://terminalcitymarketing.com/drafts/highgate/

Comment: Could you include the relevant markup here? This helps narrow things down so we have an easier time debugging. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Sorry, it's a WordPress site so the code isn't formatted well and the styles are coming from a few different stylesheets - bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if they are both in the same place, just chrome is showing you the region differently in the inspector to FF.  I don't think its an issue at all.

Comment: Virtually elements are in the same place, except for that blue background behind the pictures of the Doctors which is a relatively positioned DIV.

Answer (score 0):

on line 72 of the css, i took out the

```
 p{
 margin-bottom:12px;
 }
```

and it fixed the positioning of the green view all button.  You will then have to reapply the margins more specifically to the elements you want them on

Comment: It looks like Wordpress was wrapping some of my HTML comments in P tags. I commented out the line you mentioned, it helped, but it's still off.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that if you fix some of your [Validation Errors](http://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fterminalcitymarketing.com%2Fdrafts%2Fhighgate%2F), the problem might fix itself. Of the ones listed, the immediate red-flags that I noticed were that you have a bunch of these errors:

> Error: Duplicate ID

Check `#wrapper`, `#mainBox`, etc.